# Non-homeomorphic spaces that have continuous bijections between them

Tags: gn.general-topology, big-list, examples

What are nice examples of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are **not** homeomorphic but there do exist continuous bijections $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$?

Comment: Here are a couple of examples from Omar Antolín-Camarena: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/theme-and-variations-schroeder-bernstein/#comment-1134. He's on MO, too: http://mathoverflow.net/users/644/omar-antolin-camarena. Maybe he'll want to elaborate.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Recycling an old (ca. 1998) sci.math post:

" Anyone know an example of two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ 
 with continuous bijections $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that 
 $f$ and $g$ are not homeomorphisms?

Let $X = Y = Z \times \{0,1\}$ as sets, where $Z$ is the set of integers. 
We declare that the following subsets of $X$ are open for each $n>0$. 
$$\{(-n,0)\},\ \ \{(-n,1)\},\ \ \{(0,0)\},\ \ \{(0,0),(0,1)\},\ \ \{(n,0),(n,1)\}$$
This is a basis for a topology on $X$.

We declare that the following subsets of $Y$ are open for each $n>0$. 
$$\{(-n,0)\},\ \ \{(-n,1)\},\ \ \{(0,0),(0,1)\},\ \ \{(n,0),(n,1)\}$$
This is a basis for a toplogy on $Y$.

Define $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ by $f((n,i))=(n,i)$ and $g((n,i))=(n+1,i).$ 
Then $f$ and $g$ are continuous bijections, but $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.

This example is due to G. Paseman.

David Radcliffe "

More generally, take a space X with three successively
finer topologies T, T' and T''.  Form two spaces which have underlying
set ZxX, and "form the infinite sequences"  .... T T T T' T'' T'' T'' ....
and ... T T T T T'' T'' T'' T'' ....  The continuous maps will take a finer
topology in one sequence to a rougher topology in the other.  You can
make them bijective, and show that they are obviously non-homeomorphic
for a judicious choice of X, T, T', and T''.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.05

Comment: If you want non-compact variations on this, e.g. making the two big spaces normal or connected, then choose X and the T's even more judiciously, and add an extra point or two as needed.  And check your work, of course! I leave the compact version(s), or their impossibility, to you. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.05

Answer (score 47):

I know this is super old, but somebody asked the same question again ([Non-homeomorphic topological spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251022)) and so I wanted to share a "proof by picture" that settles the question.

(I came up with this a few years ago when I was grading an exam in which somebody claimed that $X$ and $Y$ are necessarily homeomorphic.)

Of course, this is just a special case of the accepted answer above. But I think it's nice to picture it in a geometric way...

[image]

Comment: This pictoric view looks like the Eilenberg swindle.

Comment: all you really need to show is the last 3 figures.

Comment: Aren’t $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic? They’re both infinite products of $S^1$ and $[0,1)$.

Comment: @D.Wynter: They're not infinite products, they're infinite disjoint unions of some specific finite products of those.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a continuum analogue of Gerhard Paseman's answer:  Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces whose underlying sets are $\mathbb{R}$.  As topological spaces, $X$ is the disjoint union of the open interval $(0,\infty)$ with a discrete space whose points are nonpositive reals, while $Y$ is the disjoint union of $(-1,0)$, $(1,\infty)$, and a discrete space whose points form the complement of those intervals.  Translation by adding one is a continuous bijection from $X$ to $Y$, and also a continuous bijection from $Y$ to $X$, but the two spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I like the example, but I do not see a good proof that they are not homeomorphic.  Is e.g. (3,5) an open set in both X and Y, or just a subset of an open set?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.05

Comment: Look at the one-point compactifications, after noting that both spaces are locally compact Hausdorff. For $X$ we get a disjoint union of a circle and uncountably many points, while for $Y$ we get a disjoint union of a wedge of two circle and uncountably many points. If $X$ and $Y$ were homeomorphic, their one-point compactifications would be as well.

Comment: Look at the number of non-singleton connected components: $X$ has one and $Y$ has 2. This is a topological invariant.

Answer (score 9):

I've asked myself this question some time ago and found some counterexamples. After having done this I asked myself what the "smallest" counter example would be. First of all notice that if the set of opens in $X$ and in $Y$ have to have the same cardinality. This show that that if the number of opens in $X$ is finite then $f$ and $g$ both have to be homeomorphisms so the cardinality of the set of opens needs to be at least $\aleph_0$. The answer of Gerhard Paseman shows that using $2^{\aleph_0}$ opens is enough. But one can do better, here is an example that actually has $\aleph_0$ opens:

Let $X$ and $Y$ both have $\mathbb Z$ as underlying set, let the opens of $X$ be $\lbrace \mathbb Z_{\geq i} \mid i \in \mathbb N_{>0} \rbrace \cup \lbrace  \emptyset, \mathbb Z \rbrace$ and the set of opens of $Y$ be $\lbrace \mathbb Z_{\geq i} \mid i \in \mathbb N_{>0} , i\neq 2\rbrace \cup \lbrace  \emptyset, \mathbb Z \rbrace$, then $f:X\to Y$ given by $f(x)=x$ is continues, and so is $g:Y\to X$ given by $g(a)=a-2$. To see that $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic note that $X$ contains only 1 element that is contained in exactly 2 opens, namely the element $1$, but in $Y$ both the element $1$ and the element $2$ are contained in exactly 2 opens.

Answer (score 6):

You may find the paper ["Bijectively related spaces. I. Manifolds"](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102710777) by P. H. Doyle and J. G. Hocking intersting. They cite some related work, which is also worth checking.

There is a later paper ["Unusual and bijectively related manifolds"](http://at.yorku.ca/i/a/a/j/71.htm) by J. G. Hocking on this topic, which I have not read.

If you are also interested in spaces satisfying only low separation axioms, you may try my own humble work [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11083-009-9111-2) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.5085).

Answer (score 4):

I just posted an answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87834/continuous-bijections-vs-homeomorphisms) related MO question. To sum up the part that's relevant here:

Let $\mathcal N$ be the Baire space and let $X$ be any other zero-dimensional Polish space that is not $\sigma$-compact. Then there are continuous bijections $\mathcal N \to X$ and $X \to \mathcal N$.

I don't have a short proof of this assertion, but you can look at [my paper](https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/cumet2.pdf) for a proof, and at [another paper](https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/ucr.pdf) of mine (joint with Arnie Miller) where some similar things are explored.

Now, let's fix a particularly nice $X$: say $X$ is the disjoint sum of $\mathcal N$ and the Cantor space $\mathcal C$. For this special case, I *can* give you a short proof that they're bijectively related (modulo a few well-known results).

To get a continuous bijection $\mathcal N \to X$:

By Exercise 7.15 in Kechris's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, a nonempty Polish space $Y$ is perfect if and only if there is a continuous bijection $\mathcal N \to Y$. $X$ meets these requirements.

To get a continuous bijection $X \to \mathcal N$:

There is a homeomorphic copy of $\mathcal C$, say $K$, with $K \subseteq \mathcal N$. By Theorem 7.7 in Kechris's book, $\mathcal N \setminus K$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal N$. Thus we can get a continuous bijection $X \to \mathcal N$ by mapping $\mathcal C$ homeomorphically onto $K$ and mapping $\mathcal N$ homeomorphically onto $\mathcal N \setminus K$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have my copy of Kelley handy but I think in chapter 1 he gives the example where X is a countable disjoint union of open intervals and a countable discrete set while Y is a countable disjoint union of left-closed, right-open intervals and a countable discrete set.The point is that you can get a half closed interval from an open one by attaching an endpoint and you can build an open interval using a sequence of half closed intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which comes from using the spaces of Charles Siegel's post.

One have a continuous bijection from [0,1) to the circle given by the
exponential function ( t-->exp(2ipit) ). The idea is to use this to
construct our spaces.
Take A to be a wedge of countably many (one for each integer) [0,1)
attached at 0.
Let A_n be the same wedge but replacing the [0,1) corresponding to the
integers from 1 to n by circles.

X is going to be the disjoint union of A_2, A_4, A_6,... and countably
many copies of A.
Y is going to be the disjoint union of A_1, A_3, A_5,... and countably
many copies of A.

We have a continuous bijection from A_n to A_{n+1} given by replacing
the copy of [0,1) corresponding to the integer n+1 by a circle (as it
is in A_{n+1}). Using this maps we are going to define f and g.

f is going to map one copy of A to A_1, A_2 to A_3, A_4 to A_5,... and
so on, and the rest of the copies of A to the rest of the copies of A
in Y.
g is going to map A_1 to A_2, A_3 to A_4,... and so on, and the copies
of A to the copies of A.

Answer (score 0):

What about $X= \mathbb R$ with usual topology and $Y=[a,b]$ with subspace topology?
Then $(a,b)$ is a subspace of $[a,b]$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and $[a,b]$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R$ which is homeomorphic to $[a,b]$.

Comment: The question here asks about bijections. This seems to be related more to  this: [Homeomorphism(topological spaces) version of Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/985911).

Answer (score -4):

My favorite, which is on the wikipedia page for "homeomorphism", is $\phi:[0,2\pi)\to S^1$, by $\phi(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, which is continuous and bijective, but not a homeomorphism.

Comment: The OP also wants a continuous bijection in the other direction.

Comment: Ahh! Missed that.  My apologies.